# Can move.js work with Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Ext.Anim is hard to track down, but there looks like there's some simpler libraries to chain animations, such as move.js (https://github.com/visionmedia/move.js).

Would like to use this but getting two errors:

1) document.body is undefined
2) `el.style` undefined here: `el.style[key] = val;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the first error is because Sencha hasn't initialized body yet, put your include after  in index.html or somewhere else.

The second element is because Move.js expects the dom for the element.  Try to pass this (given `source` is a Sencha element), note the reference to `.dom`:

```
    move(source.element.dom)
        .to(500, 200)
        .end();
```